# Access denied when trying to upload SQL files

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin, and have set up a database and a user with all privileges, however when I go to upload the SQL files, I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1045, Access Denied

I’m not sure what the issue is as I’'ve tried upload other SQL files without any problems.

The files in question, are found [here](http://samiltons.co.uk/_installation/).

Comment: How are you 'uploading' the files? Copy/pasting the SQL and running it, or running an import?

Comment: PHPmyadmin,uploading form Desktop.

Comment: Are either of the files working? I noticed you had one that created the DB and one to create the table.

Comment: I think ill just copy and paste. Im not too familiar with SQL, is there a way to paste the whole code  for the "02-create-and-fill-users-table.sql" file rather than create the columns and set the properties?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permissions issue. Double check to make sure you have the phpadmin username/password set correctly, and make sure you've flushed the privileges.

http://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/

Comment: Would you happens to know where i can paste the SQL code for ""02-create-and-fill-users-table.sql", rather than importing both the files?

Comment: When all else fails, command line is the way to go (if you have access).

In phpMyAdmin, one of the buttons at the top (right of the house) will open a "query window". That would be the place to paste the query.